# Does Trello send email notifications?

Tags: email, notifications, trello

Does Trello send email notifications when a task is modified? Or do we have to log in and check to see if tasks have been updated?

Answer (score 11):

Currently, Trello will send you an email notification if

- You were added to a card
- You were invited to something
- A card you were assigned to changed

The default setting is to email you a collection of unread notifications about every hour. You can change how frequently you receive email notifications at https://trello.com/your/account

Answer (score 2):

Types of Notifications

**When subscribed to a card, you’ll get notifications for…**

- All comments from other users
- Adding, changing, and upcoming due dates
- Card moves and archives

**When subscribed to a list or board…**

- You’ll get the same notifications listed above, but for all cards in a list or board.
- You’ll also get notifications for all newly created cards

**And at any time, you’ll get notifications when…**

- You are mentioned in a comment.
- You are added to a card, board, or team.
- You are mentioned in a checklist item.
- One of your boards is closed.
- When someone makes you an admin of a board or team.

You can also  subscribe to cards, lists, and entire boards to receive notifications for updates to those items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Subscribe" to a list to get notifications - click right hand button on top of the list and click "Subscribe"