# Why doesn't Trello notify me of actions that happen on my boards, even though I've set it to Instant Notification?

Tags: trello, notifications

We started using Trello within my company, and we love it. But there is one thing that could be a total deal breaker: email notifications are not working as expected. According to [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/does-trello-send-email-notifications), we should receive notifications via email when added to a card, invited to something or a card we were assigned to changed. None of these happens to us. Yes, we did turned on email notifications, I even have it set up to send them immediately.

Also, when I first started using it on Google Chrome, it asked me if I wanted to allow Trello show notifications, which I did. Never seen a chrome notification popping up either.

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of the way Trello notifications work, not a bug. We only notify you on stuff you don't see. So if you keep a browser window open with Trello on it, you won't get notifications (for now).

Subscriptions to boards and cards, which is forthcoming, should address the need for email notification on new actions. For now, notifications only notify on stuff that happens while you're away.

Comment: Thanks Rich! I exchanged some emails with Brett this week and got it figured out. I told him it seemed weird to me, but I get the point. So for now, I'm using [this chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/njdieefhcpknaagcfkgdccfdjalnkbll) to keep me updated on the notifications.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure my experience matches Rich's explanation there. If I am logged out of all machines and have no browser tag open, and something changes on my boards, I do not get an email. Ever. In fact, I never get email from Trello, at all, it seems to me. And I have notifications set to "instant" on my profile. What gives there?